# Citation within caption => avoid italics (biblatex)

Tags: fonts, biblatex, formatting, citing

In my document, the captions are set in italics. I use a customized `biblatex` author/year citation style.

If I `\cite` within a caption, the citation is set in italics as well. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`biblatex` offers the `\AtEveryCite` hook:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCite{\normalfont}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\itshape
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure \autocite{A01}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The standard latex `cite` has a formatting hook `\@cite@ofmt` other packages may offer different interfaces to setting this but something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cite@ofmt#1{\hbox{\reset@font #1}}
\makeatother
```

probably does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, David's answer didn't work for me.
But based on his solution, I added `\reset@font` which worked for me:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\reset@font\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}
\usebibmacro{cite}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```