# Natbib hook for italicised captions

Tags: fonts, captions, citing, natbib

Identical to [Citation within caption => avoid italics (biblatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63806/) just for natbib: Captions are italicised, how can I enforce `\cite{ref}` in a caption to behave like `\textup{\cite{ref}}` (other than replacing every such occurrence of the former with the latter)?

Is there a similar hook like `\AtEveryCite` for natbib (I would prefer not to hack the `\cite` macro, not sure why, happy to hear why this is an okay solution too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `\upshape` to the `\cite` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\cite
    {\begingroup\upshape\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue\NAT@swatrue
      \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@cites}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@cites}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\itshape

normal text \cite{knuth:ct:c} normal text

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```